# How to get ID from JSON object in react.js ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a 1-D array of JSON objects. In each of these objects there are some properties associated to it e.g. Name, ID, Address etc.
I want to get ID of all objects from this JSON array in react.js ES6.
Can anyone please help me do it?

```
if(entities.length > 0) {
      let assignees = [];
      entities.map(id => {
        this.props.entities.map(entity => {
          if (id === entity.id) {
            assignees.push(entity.name);
            assignees.push(<br />);
          } else if (id !== entity.id && entities.indexOf(entity.id) !== -1) {
            console.log(entities.indexOf(entity.id));
            console.log("[");
            console.log(id);
            console.log(entity.id);
            console.log("]");
            assignees.push('Unknown');
            assignees.push(<br />);
          }
        });
      });
      return assignees;
    } else {
      return(
        <span>Unassigned</span>
      );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far? Thanks

Comment: Also show us the object.. We can't help you if you don't help us understand.

Comment: if(entities.length > 0) {
      let assignees = [];
      entities.map(id => {
        this.props.entities.map(entity => {
          if (id === entity.id) {
            assignees.push(entity.name);
            assignees.push(<br />);
          } else if (id !== entity.id && entities.indexOf(entity.id) !== -1) {
            assignees.push('Unknown');
            assignees.push(<br />);
          }
        });
      });
      return assignees;
    } else {
      return(
        <span>Unassigned</span>
      );
    }

Comment: Can you show us your json?

Comment: please see updated question. @SGN

Comment: please see updated question. @JeffHuijsmans

Comment: please see updated question. @Dan

Comment: How does `entities` look like? Are you sure it's an array of ids? Because you have a json array `entity_ids`

Comment: There are two arrays. entities contains objects which have ID's and "entity_ids" is another array which contains only ID's.  What i want to do is to check if ID's present in enitity_ids are also present in entities array or not. 
  @Nocebo

Comment: So you have two arrays on the same level? Or an array within another array? Because I can only see entity_ids.

Comment: Yeah. i actually have two separate arrays. @Nocebo

Comment: Yeah I get that. But are those arrays on the same level?

Comment: What is meant by same level? can you please clarify me? @Nocebo

Comment: Nevermind it's resolved :D I thought you might have had an array within another array. So your entity_ids would have been within entities. That would have changed your comparison logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let entities = [];
let assignees = [];

// create data for test

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  entities.push({
    ID: Math.random() * 100
  });
}
entities.reduce((prev, crt) => {
    prev.push(crt.ID);
    return prev;
  },
  assignees);

console.log('Assignees', assignees);
```

here

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your array of objects and push the IDs into a new array.

```
var json_entities = [{ id: 1, ... }, { id: 2, ... }];
var ids = [];
json_entities.forEach( function(entity) {
    ids.push(entity.id);
});
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The preferred functional way of handling this is to use `map`.

```
const ids = this.props.entities.map(entity => entity.id);
```